# New Emacs frames have overly large minibuffer window

Tags: emacs

ON a couple of FreeBSD systems (versions 12 and 13) with Emacs 27 installed from binary packages, whenever I create a new frame (including the first one), it creates a frame the default size, with the first line of the file at the top of it, then the border line, then the minibuffer takes up the rest of the frame (20 lines or so). If I make any adjustment to frame size by dragging the boundaries, it changes the mini-buffer to a normal size, and uses the rest of the frame height for lines from the file. If I open a file in an existing frame that's working right, the new file also works right (most of the frame for file lines, just a few lines for mini-buffer at the bottom).  So the problem is fairly clearly somehow associated with creating frames rather than opening files.

These frames are being displayed via X11 over ssh, using vcXsrv on Windows 10 (one of the FreeBSD systems is a local VM, the other is a jail on a physical FreeBSD server).

I've looked carefully at my .emacs file, and played with anything having to do with frames or mini-buffer (there isn't anything in my .emacs file referring to the mini-buffer), and I can't find anything that seems relevant, and the things I've tried changing have made no difference.

Been googling this on and off for months, haven't been able to find anything describing anything like this. Except for having to manually tweak the frame size on each new frame, everything is working fine with emacs on these systems. Any ideas?

Comment: To help you narrowing down the error, maybe you could first check whether you can reproduce the error with "vanilla" emacs (`emacs -q`). If not, the it must come from your config. Then, still in your vanilla emacs, you can open your config file and load it section by section, until you can reproduce the error again.

Comment: Results of that are interesting. The new frames come up as just a few lines, rather than as just 1 line of file plus many lines of minibuffer. My config adds height and width to auto-frame-alist; so that kind of sounds like the default frame is coming out very small for some unclear reason, and my config is making the frame bigger but it's not getting divided conventionally?

Comment: From your description by default the minibuffer window in new frames is large, instead of just one-line high. (I'm assuming you don't see a single-line minibuffer window with just a huge font.) Also check whether `emacs -Q` shows the same problem as `emacs -q`. It's better to provide a recipe to repro the problem, starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Font sizes are as expected, yes; I do appear to get a a many-line minibuffer window.

I'll try out -Q (*I* haven't put anything in site-start.el, but there may be something relevant in the standard one). 

The latest place I'm seeing this was installed from scratch yesterday, that's part of what kicked me into digging into this, vastly less chance that I've done something weird I don't remember :-) .

Comment: Okay, further testing. 

I removed my ~/.Xresources file (which had some emacs stuff in it), and I started emacs with -Q, skipping my init file and any site-start.el. (I don't have an ~/.Xdefaults file.)

I'm running in an xterm via remote X. When I type "emacs -Q maxbw.sh" it creates a new emacs window with that file open in it. The window shows 3 lines of the file, plus a 1-line minibuffer. This new emacs window is less than 1/4 of the monitor height, and less than 1/2 of the width (it's a 1920x1080 laptop screen).

Comment: Emacs reports that it is version 27.2. I installed it as a pkg from the default FreeBSD repositories. FreeBSD itself is 13.1-RELEASE, also installed from binary packages.

Comment: So -- something in the default setup, or somewhere I haven't thought to look, is setting the file area of the window to something unreasonably small, it looks like. My init file, if run, expands the *frame* but does not change the file area; so that makes a big frame with a small file area and a big minibuffer. With my init file out of the picture, I get a small frame, with a normal minibuffer. Both have an unreasonably small area for the actual file editing.

Comment: Tried creating a new user, with no non-default config files or anything; emacs behaved exactly the same way when logged in to that user via SSH.